How does flashing in spells that prevent players from casting spells interact with spells already on the stack?
I've cast a creature spell, like Apocalypse Hydra, and as it is on the stack, before it resolves, my opponent activates Alchemist's Refuge to grant their nonland cards flash. They then flash in Aether Storm. Does Aether Storm prevent Apocalypse Hydra from resolving?
Similarly, what if they cast Academic Probation, naming Apocalypse Hydra? Does it resolve the first and not let me cast any further Apocalypse Hydras or does it stop with the first?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Casting a spell and eventually resolving it are different events. Cards such as Aether Storm and Academic Probation have no interaction with spells that have already been cast.
Casting a spell is the action of taking a spell from where it is, paying its cost, and putting it on the stack, nothing more. That process can't be interrupted. Once it's done, the spell has been cast; the casting event has happened and cannot be prevented retroactively. Any such cast-preventing effect has to be active before the affected player would have started casting that spell.
Resolving a spell is another matter entirely; casting a spell and resolving it are of course highly correlated, but still separate from each other. There are ways to prevent spells from resolving, the overwhelmingly most common of which is countering that spell. Aether Storm etc. say nothing about resolving the affected spells, so they don't interact with that part.
